# Placing a Test Order (Craft Commerce)

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ordering, order

This is a really basic question but I have had trouble finding an answer, or documentation on it.

What is the best way to place a test order with a default Craft Commerce installation? I'm unable to get past the payment page while using the default 'dummy' payment method. I would like to test the order process, including confirmation page, email confirmation, order history, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the example templates, the dummy gateway should be enough to submit an order. Are you displaying any error flash message from the payment controller?

```
<div class="flash">{{ craft.session.getFlash('notice') }}</div>
<div class="flash">{{ craft.session.getFlash('error') }}</div>
```

The dummy gateway also expects a credit card that ends in an even number in order return a success:

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-gateways#dummy-gateway

Comment: Thanks for the response! Tried a fresh install to double check — no go. I do get an error below the credit card input if the number is invalid. If not, still no response. Nothing shows up in the header on the front end, but the 'flash' elements are present in the header template.

Comment: Circling back on this, my own credit card did not work, but the one suggested in the documentation ( `4929000000006` ) did! Thank you, Luke.